# I want to print my string array elements backwards?

Tags: java, arrays

I have created an array and i want to print the array elements backwards.
I'm completely lost on how to do that. I was thinking I might need to convert this array to a char array. The example below is the method I used to print out the elements in the array. I need a new method that prints each word backwards.

Example:
Bird
DriB

```
public static void t(String [] list) throws IOException
{
    for (int i = 0; i <list.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: for each `String` in `String[]`, `String` -> `char[]`\ iterate reverse order

Answer (score 1):

No need for libraries, plain Java will do

```
new StringBuilder("Bird").reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can using [Apache commons StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#reverse(java.lang.String))

```
public static void t(String [] list) throws IOException
{
   for (int i = 0; i <list.length; i++)
   {
      String element = list[i];
      String reverseElement = StringUtils.reverse(element);
      System.out.println(reverseElement);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void t(String [] list) throws IOException
{
    for (int i = list.length; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Count bakwards?